# Memcache and Python

Tags: python, cache, memcached

I installed Memcache doing this:

```
gunzip memcached-1.2.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf memcached-1.2.1.tar
cd memcached-1.2.1
./configure
make
make install
```

Now, what exactly is the next step? (for Python)
I know there are two modules, but my friend wants me to install memcachedb. Do I install that? After I do that, how do I start the service and start using it?

Comment: What steps have you taken? The manuals are pretty clear on what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcachedb is a different beast from memcached. It's persistent storage and not caching. It's compatible with the memcached protocol so you can use the same libraries. As Xorlev notes, memcached comes with some good documentation. As far as next steps with Python you just need to decide which client library best meets your needs.